# append field to record array?

Tags: python, numpy

If I define a structured array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([(1, 'O', 1)],
             dtype=np.dtype([('step', 'int32'),
                             ('symbol', '|S1'),
                             ('index', 'int32')]))
```

seems fine until I do this:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rec
rec.append_fields(x,'x',x['index']+1)
```

gives me

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()
```

presumably because `x.shape` is (1,) rather than (1,3). How do I append columns to this structured array?

Comment: Strange, for me this works fine as expected (numpy 1.5).

Comment: Your code works for me.  What version of Python/NumPy are you using?

Comment: This is a bug in older versions of numpy (such as 1.3.0). It seems to only affect structure arrays of shape (1,).

Comment: I am working with version 1.4 on OSX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all. On NumPy 1.4.1 this was giving me the error but I just upgraded to the git 2.0 version and it works fine.